# CodeMirror how to replace marked text without removing mark

Tags: codemirror

I am adding a css style to all occurrences of a given word in a text-box using CodeMirror .
editor.markText(s, e, "cssClass");

But I would like to replace the words at the same time.

I have tried:

editor.replaceRange("new words", s, e); 
but this removes the marks as well.

I could use jquery $(".cssClass").text("new Words");

but I am worried this would mess up CodeMirror internally if it holds outdated versions of the text.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, simply messing up the dom to insert new text won't work.

If you want markers to survive the text that's marked being replaced, you'll have to make your own code manually restore them. Markers are tied to the text, so if the text is killed/replaced, so are they.

Answer (score 0):

The way I go about marking/selecting after editing is using editor.setSelection(s, e);
Not sure if this solves your problem...